# Why don't two equivalent propositions contribute to the same semantics?

Tags: logic, semantics, propositions

We often have 2 propositions that have the same truth table, in that they are true and false given the same conditions.

Nevertheless, we still feel as though there different semantics (i.e meaning..), lurking in the background.

Example : the **law of non-contradiction: ~(P ∧ ~P)**, and the proposition **if P then P, (P → P)** have the same truth table:

```
╔═══╦═══════════╦═════════╗
║ P ║ ~(P · ~P) ║ (P → P) ║
╠═══╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ F ║     T     ║    T    ║
╠═══╬═══════════╬═════════╣
║ T ║     T     ║    T    ║
╚═══╩═══════════╩═════════╝
```

But when translated into English, we can see that a semantic layer emerges, which is not contained in the logical form. Mainly, these two propositions seem to have a different meaning:

**Law of non-contradiction:** It is not the case that a cat is white and not-white.

**If P then P:** If a cat is white then it is white.

The second proposition, does not say anything about white being not-not-white as the first proposition implies.

The law of non-contradiction seems to determine what **not-** stands for, in that nothing can be and not-be.

While the second proposition does not imply this meaning of non-contradiction.

In our example, the first proposition implies that a cat cannot be white and not-white at the same time, while the second only asserts that if it is a white then it is white (without saying anything about the not- case)

Although both have the same truth table.

Why is that? Are there any philosophical resources to study these propositions on a semantic level? And how does meaning emerge from propositions with the same terms (i.e: letters like P), and the same truth table?

Thanks

**Note** I am personally inclined to say that the different semantics are due to the meaning already encoded in the propositional symbols (· , → , ~ ) and the parentheses '(' and ')', but I need some resources to look into this in further detail.

Comment: Is your question essentially: what is there more to semantic meaning than truth conditions? If so, the answer is: *a lot*, and you may want to take a look here: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/meaning/#SemThe.

Comment: The truth-functional propositional logic is a very very very simplified model of language... and it is very very very useful. But it is a model.

Comment: The basic assumption of truth-functional propositional logic is exactly that "meaning" is equated with truth value.

Comment: But still, the two are "similar" : both instances of the same tautology express a "trivial" truth. In classical logic we have *double negation* law; thus "If a cat is white then it is white" is the same as "If a cat is white then it is not the case that it is not-white". And this, in turn, is quite similar to "It is not the case that a cat is white and not-white."

Comment: @Eliran Yes, that's a good approximation to my question, thank you for the link

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree ... Don't you think that the propositional symbols are the factor that contributes to this difference in meaning? Because, if the truth table is the same, the terms are the same, then the only source of difference would be in if...then, and , not- ...etc.

Comment: Although sometimes, the meaning is conserved when we convert if..then to an And, like in If p then q, and not-(p and not-q).

Comment: "Why don't two equivalent propositions contribute to the same semantics?" [Many prominent philosophers of language have argued that they do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slingshot_argument), although they usually differ on the questions of "in which contexts" and "to what extent".

Comment: @Not_Here  "Slingshot argument" , sounds interesting, thank you, something new to learn today.

Comment: Isn't the idea of equivalence that things are equal in some respects but not others? Otherwise we'd say they are the same or identical. So why *would* they have the same semantics? Because of the same truth table? But x(x-1) and x^2-x also specify the same real function, but different ways of computing it, so the meanings are different. And natural language connectives are not even specifiable by truth tables at all, e.g. [implication is non-truth functional](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/compositionality/#Cond).

Comment: @Conifold Thanks , I am not saying that they should have the same semantics, I am asking where does the difference in semantics come from? and I suggested that the difference comes from the logic symbols like if ... then, and, not-...etc.

Comment: That is partly right. Connectives come with pre-existent ("intuitive") semantics, which is only approximately tracked by the truth functional definitions. In the (non-truth functional) intuitionistic logic some classically equivalent formulas are no longer equivalent, e.g. ~(P ∧ ~P) is still derivable, but ~P∨P is not. However, even if we stick to the strictly truth functional connectives of classical logic equivalent logical formulas would still have a differentiating layer of semantics, because they specify different ways of computing truth values.

Comment: I could not agree more @Conifold , although there is still something puzzling about these semantics, maybe the question itself is wrong, or maybe semantics are very ambiguous and allows for this fuzziness compared to symbolic logic. Thanks again.

Comment: I think the puzzlement comes from mixing the narrow and broad sense of "semantics". In 19th century Frege replaced the hazy notion of "meaning" with "semantic value", which for a sentence is its truth value, for a predicate its truth value function, for a connective its classical truth table, etc. In formal contexts "semantics" refers to something like Fregean redux. But the informal notion of meaning did not go away. Same with functions. In 18th century they were identified with formulas, so x(x-1) and x^2-x were different. Then came modern value-based definition, and now they are the "same".

Comment: @Conifold I see, thank you.. I am currently looking for good books on semantics.

Comment: My favorite exposition of Fregean semantics, its shortfalls, fixes, and what came after is [Miller's Philosophy of Language](https://books.google.com/books/about/Philosophy_of_Language.html?id=7hPy6ZrMZ-AC).